# Define /mp-rest/url for all clients at once Quarkus YAML

Tags: java, yaml, quarkus

In Quarkus, I am able to define the base url for my clients in my YAML file via the /mp-rest/url property. Currently my YAML file looks like this:

```
...

"%dev":
  some:
    package:
      name:
        client:
          ExampleService1/mp-rest/url: https://some.url.com
          ExampleService2/mp-rest/url: https://some.url.com

"%tst":
  some:
    package:
      name:
        client:
          ExampleService1/mp-rest/url: https://some.other.url.com
          ExampleService2/mp-rest/url: https://some.other.url.com

...
```

As you can see I have multiple services which all have the same base url in their respective development environments (all dev base urls are the same, and all tst base urls are the same).

As I have the same base url for each environment's services, I don't want to have to define the url for each service I have.

**My Question:**
Is there a way for me to define the /mp-rest/url for ALL services in my client folder at once?
It would have to look something like this (obviously this doesn't work):

```
"%dev":
  some:
    package:
      name:
        client:
          */mp-rest/url: https://some.url.com
"%tst":
  some:
    package:
      name:
        client:
         */mp-rest/url: https://some.other.url.com
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a single configuration that you can use in all your REST Client.

First, define the configuration with a custom name instead of the default package + class name:

```
country-api/mp-rest/url=https://restcountries.eu/rest
```

Then tell the REST client to use this custom configuration instead of the default one :

```
@RegisterRestClient(configKey="country-api")
public interface CountriesService {
    [...]
}
```

You can find more information here:
https://quarkus.io/guides/rest-client#create-the-configuration

**EDIT : for application.yml something like this should works**

```
country-api/mp-rest/url: https://restcountries.eu/rest
```

Comment: This is for a application.properties file though, I want to do this in my YAML file.

Comment: The exemple shows application.properties but the same can be done in yaml. The idea is to define a single configuration root property (here `country-api`) that will be used instead of the default fully qualified class name. Then references this config root inside the `@RegisterRestClient` annotation.
I'll add a config exemple for yaml.

Comment: Thanks, I wasn't aware, after fiddling with it for a bit i found it this is the syntax:


`base-url/mp-rest/url: some.url.com`

And then use `@RegisterRestClient(configKey="base-url")`

Comment: Ah yes, I saw the difference. The '/' is not an object delimiter so it should be on the yaml key, I'll update my answer.